# Can Omniknight's Repel skill offset any enemy's buff?

Tags: dota-2

Can I use Omniknight's Repel to offset any enemy's buff?

I am asking because I know Repel removes Guardian Angel effect on friendly unit if Repel is cast on ally target after Guardian Angel and while it is still effective.

Is there any point it is designed in the way that it can be cast on an  enemy target?

Comment: Note: You can cast the other way around first repel then guardian angel, to keep both effects.

Comment: @zozo Yes, I am aware of that. Still, thank you for your comment.

Comment: One fun way to use it is to cast it on an enemy right before Naga's song, letting you 5v1, and then 5v4 when the song ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and that's all the point. Be aware that you can also remove the effect of a rune (like the haste rune) aswell

However keep in mind that this will make your enemy magic imune.

Comment: Could you please specify a list of buff that can be removed by Repel if possible? I tried on Dazzle's Shallow Grave once, it didn't work. But I assume it will remove Bloodseeker's Blood rage?

Comment: @Conan http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Purge#List_of_Abilities_that_cannot_be_Purged